# overriding the $content_width in wordpress not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to reset the $content_width variable as per the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width)

In my functions.php I put `$content_width = 2000;`

I am then creating some new images sizes for the media library. I know these images are uploading with my new sizes because I checked with ftp and the filenames are correct but they are displaying wrong in the media pop up for images sizes and so the width settings are wrong int he code. This is exactly the problem described on the link but the solution, at least for me, isn't working

Can anyone help please?

E

Comment: In your Settings check the Media menu, and see if the images are being cropped there.

Comment: thanks - done that. The images are being cropped correctly - its the display, and hence the width / height tags that are wrong

Answer (score 0):

add code like this

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
    $content_width = 625;

function twentytwelve_content_width() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'full-width-page.php' ) || is_attachment() ) {
        global $content_width;
        $content_width = 960;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'twentytwelve_content_width' );
```

follow this https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21256

Comment: thanks - i have tried various combinations of your suggestion (and looked at this link) - nothing seems to work.